# Python openpyxl data validation along with formatting

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, formatting, openpyxl

I am using openpyxl to created a `.xlsx` file to aggregate some data.

One of the columns is `Status` and needs to be data-validated to make sure it only contains one of several options. I did this part just fine:

```
validator = openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation.DataValidation(type = 'list',
                                                             formula1 = ('"'
                                                                         'Option 1,'
                                                                         'Option 2,'
                                                                         'Option 3,'                                                                       
                                                                         '"'))

validator.promptTitle = 'Status Selection'
validator.prompt = 'Please select a status.'

validator.errorTitle = 'Invalid Status'
validator.error = 'Your status is not in the list of accepted entries.'

worksheet.add_data_validation(validator)

validator.add('I1:I1048576')
```

but I also need to make the options for the data validation format the cells.

[image]

This is what the column currently looks like. What I need to do is make the bg color of the cell turn for example red if `Option 1` is selected, yellow if `Option 2` is selected and green if `Option 3` is selected.

I have tried searching both here and on Google and spent some 1-on-1 time with the somewhat lackluster openpyxl documentation(I am coming straight from a few hours of staring at the data validation and conditional formatting sections there) and while the last example from conditional formatting came close to what I need I have no clue how to adapt it to my situation.

How exactly should I go about getting the effect I described? The bg color changing according to the value chosen from the data validation drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching to do the exact same thing and found this topic which helped me for the first part. Here is how I solved the second part:

```
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:'+get_column_letter(worksheet.max_column)+str(worksheet.max_row),\
CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['"Option 1"'], fill=PatternFill(bgColor="FF0000")))
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:'+get_column_letter(worksheet.max_column)+str(worksheet.max_row),\
CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['"Option 2"'], fill=PatternFill(bgColor="FFFF00")))
worksheet.conditional_formatting.add('A1:'+get_column_letter(worksheet.max_column)+str(worksheet.max_row),\
CellIsRule(operator='equal', formula=['"Option 3"'], fill=PatternFill(bgColor="00FF00")))
```

(You could adjust the formatting area if you dont need the entire sheet to be conditionnal formatted)